# Drupal: Add id to error list

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

Is there a solution to add an id to the default drupal error list items?

Currently i got this:

```
<div class="messages error" id="inline-messages">
    <ul>
        <li>Name is required.</li>
        <li>Email is required.</li>
        <li>Message is required.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But i would like to have the fieldname as id:

```
<div class="messages error" id="inline-messages">
    <ul>
        <li id="form-field-name">Name is required.</li>
        <li id="form-field-email">Email is required.</li>
        <li id="form-field-message">Message is required.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Plugins in use: `http://drupal.org/project/inline_messages`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but maybe it will still help you or someone else looking for this, the messages are themed in [theme_status_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/6) but you don't have any context about them at this point. However...

Form errors are added through [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6), which stores them in an static array according to the form field name, you can access that through [form_get_errors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_get_errors/6).

Now, you can load these errors and then look up the error messages in that error array and use the key as the id.